# How to get OuterHTML of dynamamically created control

Tags: jquery

outerHTML is undefined. But when seeing the intelligence it shows the value

[image: outerHTML is undefined. But when seeing the intelligence it shows the value]

Answer (score 4):

Since `hidden` is a jQuery object,for getting dom object you need to use `hidden[0]`

```
alert(hidden[0].outerHTML)
```

Ref : **[How do I pull a native DOM element from a jQuery object?](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/)**

Comment: Just a thought will all be hidden input be added in that object?

Comment: @Pekka: In the OP's code, there's just one hidden input in the jQuery object (set). If there were more than one, Pranav's example would get the `outerHTML` of the first. The second would be `[1]`, the third `[2]`, and so on.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes that is what i mean thank you for clarifying just want to make sure that my assumption is correct. happy coding. I just want to make sure because i might come across same issue soon.

Comment: @PranavCBalan one more question regarding hidden input is it advisable to put hidden input with value then get the value of that input to be used maybe as parameter?if not what would you suggest is a better approach?

Comment: @Pekka : hidden field can be use when you want to pass some additional data with form which is hidden from user visually.... you can use `data-*` custom attribute to store values and get it using `data()`

Comment: @BabuKumarasamy : glad to help :)

Comment: @PranavCBalan yes I can use the data attribute that one is an option which is better approach?

Comment: @Pekka : it depends on your need :)

Comment: @PranavCBalan: `data` isn't a good way to access `data-*` attributes unless you're using `data`'s various features that go beyond attributes. It sets up an entire cache of information that isn't used. To simply access the attribute, use `attr`.